# How to make a nice tab for an android app

Tags: android, xml

Im working on the design of my app, trying to make it look pretty and stuff.

[image: http://cdn1.1stwebdesigner.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/mobile-apps/jauntly-mobile-app-designs.jpg]

I really like design of the top bar on this. i could make my own images for it which i think they might be doing.

But basically does anyone know how this is done and i could do it?

any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Is it really a tab in your picture? How do we know which tab is open since it's not highlighted or anything?

Comment: emm good question, im guessing so, it could just be a link bar along the top

Comment: I don't understand the question: what specifically are you asking for? How to do a tool/menu bar?

Comment: emm basically how could i make somthing that looks like that to access different pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you probably want is to use an ActionBar.  It is somewhat limited in how you can style it, but here is an example that looks kind of like [what you are looking for](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionProvider).  Essentially if you want it to have "tabed" functionality, ie you click on one and it takes you to a different "screen", you can use fragments for each of the different screen and switch between them.

If that doesn't work for you, you could always just have a layout at the top of the screen and use image buttons for the "tabs".